# configure secure SSL Apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, ssl, https, proxy

I'm trying to establish a reverse proxy setup with apache that securely supports SSL all the way through:

```
Client   <-->   Proxy @ somehostname.com   <-->   Server @ 123.45.67.89
```

Note that my proxy server has a hostname, but the remote server does not. The SSL setup between clients and the proxy works fine with a letsencrypt setup. However, I am struggling to secure the connection between the proxy and the remote server.

Because the remote server doesn't have a hostname, and letsencrypt doesn't issue certificates for IPs only, my idea was to generate a self-signed certificate and copy the certificate over to the proxy for it to only trust that one. Unfortunately I don't know how.

If I just disable these certificate checks, the connection works, as the proxy just trusts every certificate:

```
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
```

While encryption will work fine, to my understanding authenticity is compromised and I am subject to MitM attacks during the handshake. This is not ideal.

Instead, I've instructed Apache to trust my self-signed certificate with

```
SSLProxyCACertificateFile /path/to/cert.pem
```

and then tried to enforce a valid certificate with

```
SSLProxyVerify require
```

but despite me explicitly listing the certificate, and the documentation of [`SSLProxyCACertificateFile`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslproxycacertificatefile) saying "These are used for Remote Server Authentication", it seems to not trust it.

Is there a way to make sure the connection between the proxy and remote server is safe, for example by enforcing Apache to always connect to the proxy using that specific certificate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out adding certificates via `SSLProxyCACertificateFile` does not skip name checks, which makes total sense. So in order for custom certificates to work, they still need to be issued to the correct name, or in my case, the IP. After I made a new certificate issued to that IP, my configuration works now. Here are the relevant parts:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName somehostname.com
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyVerify require
    SSLProxyCACertificateFile /path/to/custom_cert.pem
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on  # or omit, default is on
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName on  # same
    ProxyPass / https://123.45.67.89/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://123.45.67.89/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi Felk, I am facing the same issue, I have the same config than you:  C <--> Reverse Proxy <--> Server (https), as I understand to make the secured connection between Reverse Proxy and Server I need to add a trustEntry in the Reverse Proxy, and this is done via     SSLProxyCACertificateFile /path/to/custom_cert.pem correct? Thank you...

Comment: Yes. Specifying the certificate in a `SSLProxyCACertificateFile` directive basically circumvents the restriction that all certificates usually need to be issued by one of a predefined list of certificate authorities.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Felk, I've noticed that my Server is also requesting a certificate (2 way SSL ie Client Auth) in this case I would also need to have a Key in the Webserver right ? Which will be accepted (authenticated) by the Server ? Thanks

Comment: If you are facing a particular problem, please open a new question. You can link it here and ping me and I'll take a look

Comment: Ok Thanks Felk, I will elaborate it and will ping back, good day :)