# Is there any alternative to Mod_JK AJP which we can use as a secure connection between Apache and Tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-proxy, mod-jk, mod-proxy-ajp

I am currently using Mod_jk to have a connectivity between Apache and Tomcat through non-secure AJP protocol. Is there any way I can implement secure connection? Can I achieve this using mod_proxy_http and proxy over https? As far as I know using mod_proxy_http is also not a secure one.

Can anyone Guide me here? I am using Tomcat 9 and Apache 2.4 versions.

Thanks,
Anshu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure a secure connection between Apache and tomcat using Mod_proxy. Refer [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982154/configure-secure-ssl-apache-proxy/42982547#42982547) and [link2](https://serverfault.com/questions/25423/apache-virtualhost-with-mod-proxy-and-ssl) for more information.

Comment: I was using using Mod_JK and now I am implementing Mod_proxy as you suggested.Will  accept this if everything works fine. One question, Do mod_proxy provide complete encryption? somewhere I saw that mod_proxy does not provide complete encryption.

Comment: Yes. Mod_proxy provides complete encryption. i.e WebBrowser(SSL)---->Apache(SSL)------> Mod_Proxy(SSL)------> Tomcat(SSL)

Comment: ok, let me implement it and will get back to you. Thanks for your quick help.

Comment: It's working and I can see the encrypted traffic now. Thanks again, Accepting your answer.